# gtag.js tracking on multiple domains but no linking

Tags: analytics, gtag.js

My company has an angular component library that we want to track usage of.  This means that multiple developers will us it on multiple domains.  I have included a single tracking id and am dynamically loading the gtag.js library when components are loaded.  This works on the main domain but the tracking isn't logged in the dashboard.  Does anyone know of the settings required to make this possible?  Also I am not trying to link any pages or sessions, just have unique tracking per application.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had upgraded one gtag emit call but a second one was still in the ga syntax and wasn't registering in the dashboard.